# How can I append my git commit to my bin within makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to create a rule within a make file to read a git commit and append into the name of a binary, so far I am struggling with the fact that the variable that will hold the commit seems to be empty,

```
append_git_commit: $(preName)/FLASH.bin
    GIT_COMMIT=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%h)
    echo "$(info GIT_COMMIT="$(GIT_COMMIT)")"
```

shows this

```
GIT_COMMIT=
echo ""
```

Why is this? I would expect that GIT_COMMIT holds my hash like `GIT_COMMIT=62f9926a`

And secondly, how would it be the rule to append this `GIT_COMMIT` content to my `FLASH.bin` so that the result is

```
FLASH_62f9926a.bin
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your current `Makefile`.

```
GIT_COMMIT=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%h)
```

Doesn't do what you expect it to do, because, it's a make variable expansion and not a command expansion in shell. For that it to be passed to the underlying shell, you'd have to escape the `$`:

```
GIT_COMMIT=$$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%h)
```

On the next line, the `$(GIT_COMMIT)` refers to `GIT_COMMIT` make variable and not a shell variable.

Which then runs into a problem that:

- setting variable in shell executed from make does not set a make variables (also meaning `info` would have no access to what happened in the shell command above); that shell is a child process of make
- and each line of the recipe runs in its own shell instance (so variables from one line are not visible on the next one)

If I understand what you are after, I would probably do it like this:

```
GIT_COMMIT := $(shell git log -1 --pretty=format:%h)

append_git_commit: $(preName)/$(GIT_COMMIT)_FLASH.bin

$(preName)/$(GIT_COMMIT)_FLASH.bin: $(preName)/FLASH.bin
        cp "$<" "$@"
```

Using a make variable and introducing an intermediate target, as long as there is not new revision and the `$(preName)/FLASH.bin` did not get updated, there is not need to do anything for `append_git_commit` either, because it now knows it needs to create `$(preName)/$(GIT_COMMIT)_FLASH.bin` from `$(preName)/FLASH.bin` and all details are know at the time `Makefile` is being evaluated.

Comment: I have another small question. In case I wanted to delete the previous binary within this rule, how could I make it? Meaning that if I had `FLASH_62f9926a.bin`, the commit changes and this rule creates a new image, let's call it `FLASH_62f9945b.bin`, how could I remove the old `FLASH_62f9926a.bin`?

Comment: If you've moved (your repo) on, you don't really know the name unless you've also saved a previous state (e.g. in a text file). So if not a problem (getting something you did not want), you can clean by deleting `FLASH_*.bin` (or even use 8 `?`s instead). Otherwise you'd need to introduce secondary target/product saving the filename and them remove what is saved there (and the file holding the information).

Comment: Do you mean deleting prior to call the rule?

Comment: I was thinking more in terms of implementing `clean` target (which you manually call when you want previous results wiped).